# Question and Answer program crashes on release build, works fine on debug build

Tags: c++, crash

I have made a question and answer program (Console application) with 3 questions, it works just fine in CodeBlocks 17.12 (debug build), but on the release build ( the .exe file ) it crashes without any error when correctly answering the 3rd question. The program doesn't crash when putting in the wrong answer.

I tried to debug with WinDbg Preview but most of the time it didn't work and when it did the program did NOT crash when correctly answering the 3rd question and worked as normal.
I also tried to remove the SetConsoleAttribute colors, but that didn't work either.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
SetConsoleTitle("Bloodrush: The Game");
cout << "Question 3" << endl;
cout << "text" << endl;
cout << "A)" << endl;
cout << "B)" << endl;
cout << "C)" << endl;
cout << "D)" << endl;
cout << "E)" << endl;
string ANSWER3;
cin >> ANSWER3;
if ((ANSWER3 == "E") || (ANSWER3 == "e") || (ANSWER3 == "e)") || (ANSWER3 == "e)"))
 {
   if (system("CLS"))
        system("clear");
    cout << "text" << endl;
    cout << "text" << endl;
    cout << "text \n" << endl;
    cout << "text" << endl;
    return 0;
  }
    else
    {
            SetConsoleTitle("Wrong Answer");
            if (system("CLS")) system("clear");
            cout << "text \n" << endl;
            cout << "Press ENTER to return to the MAIN MENU..." << endl;
            cin.ignore();
            cin.get();
            cout << "no menu" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: The code here is not complete and does not compile. Where the crash happens?

Comment: It seems to happen right after ``` if ((ANSWER3 == "E") || (ANSWER3 == "e") || (ANSWER3 == "E)") || (ANSWER3 == "e)")) ``` I will put in the whole code if I need to.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured out what the problem was.

```
if ((ANSWER3 == "E") || (ANSWER3 == "e") || (ANSWER3 == "e)") || (ANSWER3 == "e)"))
 {
   if (system("CLS"))
        system("clear");
    cout << "text" << endl;
    cout << "text" << endl;
    cout << "text \n" << endl;
    cout << "text" << endl;
    return 0;
  }
```

In this part of the code I forgot to add

```
cin.ignore(); // These 2 commands make it so that you need to press                
cin.get();    // ENTER to continue running the program
```

So it is now

```
if ((ANSWER3 == "E") || (ANSWER3 == "e") || (ANSWER3 == "e)") || (ANSWER3 == "e)"))
 {
   if (system("CLS"))
        system("clear");
    cout << "text" << endl;
    cout << "text" << endl;
    cout << "text \n" << endl;
    cout << "text" << endl;
    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
  }
```

So now the program doesn't just shut off, it displays the text above after inputing the answer. After pressing ENTER the program will shut off.